# Mysql fetch records common records as well uncommon records

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 5 tables (`amazon`,`ebay`,`opencart`,`sears`,`jet`) I want common records from all table on first priority then common records from any of the two ya three tables tables then uncommon records.

my tables and data are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amazon` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_upc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_sku` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `amazon`
--

INSERT INTO `amazon` (`id`, `a_upc`, `a_sku`, `a_title`) VALUES
(1, 'upc_a', 'sku1', 'title_a'),
(2, 'upc1', 'sku_a', 'title_a_1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `j_upc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `j_sku` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `j_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `jet`
--

INSERT INTO `jet` (`id`, `j_upc`, `j_sku`, `j_title`) VALUES
(1, 'upc1', 'sku_j', 'title_j'),
(2, 'upc_j', 'sku_j_1', 'title1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebay` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `e_upc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e_sku` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `e_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ebay`
--

INSERT INTO `ebay` (`id`, `e_upc`, `e_sku`, `e_title`) VALUES
(1, 'upc_e', 'sku1', 'title_e'),
(2, 'upc1', 'sku_e', 'title_e_1'),
(3, 'upc_e_1', 'sku2', 'title1');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `opencart` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `o_upc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_sku` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `o_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `opencart`
--

INSERT INTO `opencart` (`id`, `o_upc`, `o_sku`, `o_title`) VALUES
(1, 'upc_a', 'sku1', 'title_o'),
(2, 'upc1', 'sku_o', 'title1');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sears` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `s_upc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_sku` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `s_title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `sears`
--
INSERT INTO `sears` (`id`, `s_upc`, `s_sku`, `s_title`) VALUES
(1, 'upc1', 'sku_s', 'title_s'),
(2, 'upc_s', 'sku_s_1', 'title_s_1');
```

Comment: I just want to suggest to make it one table, and make the company (Amazon/Sears) an extra companyId column in that table. That way, you can just add extra companies to your software without making additional changes, while in the current situation, you'll have to add a table and do a major rewrite to all your software.

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is not proper but still if you want some thing like this you can do like this.

```
select *,count(id) as priority
 from
   (
    select id,c1,c2,c3 from table1 
    union all 
    select id,c1,c2,c3 from table2 
    union all select id,c1,c2,c3 from table3
    ) t1
    groupt by id,c1,c2,c3 order by priority desc
```

its not the most optimized way..

You should create a single table and put a type or table column .

Comment: hey if its work for you, share for other and you can accept my answer also.

Comment: if you still want finding answer.. you can post you code so I can understand and help you.